# Hosted User Control in IE and Client Side Event Handling

Tags: javascript, user-controls, event-handling

I just upgraded a hosted control to .NET 2.0 and I had to enable the ComVisible to access methods from the client side using javascript.

Should events also be accessible once I enable ComVisible? I was handling my events like this before with no issues:

```
<OBJECT id="foo" ...></OBJECT>

<script language="javascript">
     function document.all.foo::SampleEvent(res){
     //do stuff here
     }
</script>
```

This won't work either:

```
<script language="javascript" for="foo" event="SampleEvent(res)">
     alert(res);
</script>
```

For some reason I can't catch my events now. If I use my DLL in a WinForms project the event handles fine so I know I've set it all up properly.

How can I expose this to the client side properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up on this in case someone runs into it in the future. I had 2 mismatched data types in the user control which was causing the event not to fire properly.

**Check your data types!**